# php - IntlDateFormatter() wrong/weird timestamp in comparison to DateTime() output

Tags: php, datetime, intldateformatter

I noticed that `IntlDateFormatter()` function returns wrong timestamp in comparison to same type of output from `DateTime()` function.

**PHP:**

```
    $formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
        'en_GB', 
        IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 
        IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 
        'Europe/London', 
        IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
        'dd MMMM YYYY, HH:mm'
    );

    $now = new DateTime('01-03-2023 17:00');                        
    echo '<b>DateTime() String:</b> ' . $now->format('d F Y, H:i') . '<br/>';
    echo '<b>IntlDateFormatter() String:</b> ' . $formatter->format( $now ) . '<br/><br/>';
    echo '<b>DateTime() Timestamp:</b> ' . $now->getTimestamp() . '<br/>';
    echo '<b>IntlDateFormatter() Timestamp:</b> ' . $formatter->parse( $formatter->format( $now ) );
```

**OUTPUT:**

> **DateTime() String:** 01 March 2023, 17:00
>
> **IntlDateFormatter()** String: 01 March 2023, 17:00
>
> **DateTime() Timestamp:** 1677690000
>
> **IntlDateFormatter() Timestamp:** 1672074000

As is visible above, `IntlDateFormatter()` returns good string, but a bad timestamp value from the same source. Why is that happen?

Comment: Worth noting that `1672074000` is `Monday, December 26, 2022 5:00:00 PM`, a full 65 _days_ off what it should be.

Comment: The format YYYY does not exist in the ICU documentation https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/. There are only y, yy, yyyy and Y. This fact combined with a misinterpretation of YYYY by the IntlDateFormatter produces the wrong timestamp.

Comment: @jspit It was not obvious for me that using of that format will not output error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When call `$formatter->parse($formatter->format($now))`, the parse method is interpreting the week year value as the year value, resulting in a different timestamp value than the DateTime object's timestamp.

To get consistent output, you can use lowercase `yyyy` instead of uppercase `YYYY` in `IntlDateFormatter`.

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_GB', 
    IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 
    IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 
    'Europe/London', 
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm'
);

$now = new DateTime('01-03-2023 17:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

echo '<b>DateTime() String:</b> ' . $now->format('d F Y, H:i') . '<br/>';
echo '<b>IntlDateFormatter() String:</b> ' . $formatter->format( $now ) . '<br/><br/>';

echo '<b>DateTime() Timestamp:</b> ' . $now->getTimestamp() . '<br/>';
echo '<b>IntlDateFormatter() Timestamp:</b> ' . $formatter->parse( $formatter->format( $now ) ) . '<br/><br/>';

echo '<b>Default Timezone:</b> ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br/>';
echo '<b>DateTime() Timezone:</b> ' . $now->getTimezone()->getName() . '<br/>';
echo '<b>IntlDateFormatter() Timezone:</b> ' . $formatter->getTimeZone()->getID() . '<br/>';
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. I just updated

Comment: You also should explicitly note that you changed the format string from `YYYY` to `yyyy` which is a very significant part of the issue. Eg: Link the [format reference](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#parsing-dates) and note the difference between `Y` "year of 'week of year'" and `y` which is the actual calendar year.

Comment: Thank You for helping me. I would never discover what you did explain. I was sure there should be some error in case of wrong format of year. When was not, I simply had emptiness in my mind and could't figure out by checking any options what is wrong.